# Bind multiple events to a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have `searchbox.onsubmit = function(){ //Function here }` and I wanted `searchbtn.onclick` to trigger the same function, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: your `function(){ }` is called an anonymous function.  If you name the function as jas7457 suggests you can reuse it as many times as you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried...

```
function handleEvent(){
}

searchbox.onsubmit = handleEvent;
searchbtn.onclick = handleEvent;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work too.

```
var myFunction = function() {
   alert("myfunc");
}

searchbox.addEventListener("submit", myFunction);
searchbtn.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
```